# Google Drive API using worksheet

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I use update() function of Google Drive API to update (with convert=true parameter) a csv file to google drive.
The result is an updated Google Spreadsheet (single worksheet)

Can I update a specificied worksheet of the file (passing the ID) ?
Every update call create a different worksheet (different ID) and I don't need it changes.
I have this problem because an external app read this file using google file ID and worksheet ID.

I use PHP API.

Thanks all

Comment: look at spreadsheet api

Comment: I have not found API to do this, can you link me. I read: "It is possible to create a new spreadsheet by uploading a spreadsheet file via the Google Drive API." (what i'm doing, but I need to set the worksheet id)

Comment: no but you can modify existing one manually not with csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the api (or by url) does not support converting a csv into an existing spreadsheet.

you could instead convert into a new sheet and then use the spreadsheet api to copy the sheet data into your spreadsheet. you can also skip the csv upload step and directly parse and write to the existing sheet using that api.